# How to compare two registers in x86-64

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm comparing two arrays in assembly character by character, the C code would be something like this:

```
   count=0;
   for (i=0;i<vector;i++) {
     if (array1[i]==array2[i]) {
       count++;
     }
   }
```

Basically, both arrays are compared and when the character in that position is the same, count is increased.

I ended up with this code in assembly, which actually seems to work as intended:

```
   forEachVector:
     cmp bl, vector
     jge endforEachVector
     mov rax, QWORD[array1+rbx] ; move array[i] to rax
     mov rdx, QWORD[array2+rbx] ; move array[i] to rdx

     if1Equals2:
     cmp dl, al
     jne fi1Equals2
     inc cl
     fi1Equals2:

     inc bl
     jmp forEachVector
   endforEachVector:
```

vector is a constant, and array1 and 2 are extern and defined in C as "char array1[vector]". 
In my understanding, array1[i] is 16 bit long because it's a char array, and a char is an int == 16 bits. Because of that, first I tried to operate with the full 64 bit registers, jut like:

```
cmp rdx, rax
```

And the code fails if I use 64bits registers (the zero bit is not set so jne is triggered and if ends), it only works only when I use al and dl (8 lsb) and I want to understand why.

It's not a problem to compare the 8 lsb because arrayX[i] is never going to be higher than 2^8, but doing cmp rax, rdx and cmp al, dl should have the same effect.

Comment: Ok, c strings store 8-bit values, not 16 bits.  Wide arrays or UTFs or others may vary, but standard C strings are 8-bits, hence your compare works.

Comment: Here is a godbolt to make sure we are understanding each other: https://godbolt.org/z/nvye_k

Answer (score 0):

`rax` is a qword register, 8 bytes = 64 bits.

A `char` is 8 bits = 1 byte, *not* 16 bits.  (And `int` is a 32-bit type for 64-bit x86 compilers.  Look at compiler-generated code if you're curious.)

**If you load 8 characters at a time and compare the whole qword registers with `cmp rdx, rax`, it's similar to a `memcmp(array1+i, array2+i, 8)`**  (But actually implement memcmp would use `bswap`, because x86 is little endian but for memcmp the *first* difference is the significant one.)

Your current code works because even though you *load* 8 bytes, you only look at the low single-byte partial register.

But your program would fault if you gave it a pointer to the last character in a page, and the next memory page was unmapped.  Your 8-byte load from the address of that last character would cross into the unmapped page and segfault.

Use `movzx eax, byte [rdi]` to load a single byte, zero-extended to a wider register.